# CSV Date Time Format changes in SAS

Tags: csv, time, sas

I imported a CSV file in SAS. ONe of the columns in the file has time as minutes from midnight. Example: 5:00AM would be 300. Its calculated as (5*60). 4:30PM would be ((16*60)+30)=990. Now I need to convert this minutes from midnight column to a regular time column that would look like 05:00:00 or 16:30:00.

How should I do this?

Comment: Have you attempted anything yet?

Comment: SAS time values are seconds from midnight, so just multiply by 60 again.

Answer (score 0):

As david25272 said, you need to multiply the column by 60. In order to format it correctly, you can apply the `time.` format